# How to add time attribute in Prisma?

Tags: mysql, database, prisma

This is one of the models from my schema:

```
model playlist {
  id              Int             @id @default(autoincrement())
  list            String          @db.VarChar(34)
  duration        DateTime?       @db.Time(0)
}
```

And I would like to add a time value when I am creating a new record. But it seems that I can only add value with the DateTime type.

I tried just passing a String but that doesnt work and I get and error.
This is the error:

```
Argument duration: Got invalid value '00:01:29' on prisma.createOneplaylist. Provided String, expected DateTime or Null.
```

Is there a way to only add the time or am I forced to use DateTime format?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would always need to send a `Date` object in this case. For e.g. this is how I would set the time using `date-fns`.

```
import set from 'date-fns/set'

await prisma.playlist.create({
    data: {
      list: 'list',
      duration: set(new Date(), { hours: 1, minutes: 10 }),
    },
})
```

A similar parsing mechanism can be used when you retrieve the time.